# Css background-image not showing up at all

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give a div class the background image of a header but it won't show up.

Please see:

http://jsfiddle.net/eqzro6s3/

[css]

```
  .header
  {
      background-image: url('http://wpsites.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Custom-Header-Image.png') no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
  }
```

[html]

```
<div class="header">
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just add the image to your HTML instead?

Comment: Jean, because UI elements should be backgrounds. They are not content. Inline images are for content.

Comment: I want to add a text box in the image that's why

Answer (score 0):

background-image is just not a short-hand property, thus you cannot use more than one value:

```
.header
  {
      background-image: url('path.png');/* remove no-repeat from here*/
      background-repeat: no-repeat; /*use no-repeat here*/
      width: 100%;
  }
```

Or, use it like this:

```
.header
  {
      /*short-hand method  can have multiple values*/
      background: url('path.png') no-repeat; 
      width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements with backgrounds need to have dimensions. They don't automatically size themselves to the background image.

```
.header
  {
      background-image: url('http://wpsites.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Custom-Header-Image.png') no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: ?????
  }
```

Comment: What are you using? I hope not "100%".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  .header
  {
      background: #FFFFFF url('http://wpsites.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Custom-Header-Image.png') left center no-repeat; 
      width:100%; 
      height:431px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/eqzro6s3/1/

Comment: Change the height of the class to 431px.

Answer (score 0):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/eqzro6s3/3/)

```
 .header{
      background: url('http://wpsites.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Custom-Header-Image.png') no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height:432px;
      }
```

change background-image: to background: